# Empty file after converting from text to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have been writing a short piece of python code to download a data file from a website and write it to a text file (which it does successfully). Now I want to take that text file and convert it to CSV format. I have been using the responses from questions like "How to convert from txt to csv" but still come to the same end, which is that the CSV file is created successfully and the code executes without error, only the CSV file is empty, short of the column titles I have defined.

```
import csv
import requests
res = requests.get('https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~saurabh/mlcs2k2/vectors_R.dat')
res.status_code = requests.codes.ok


textfile = open("textfile.txt","w")
textfile.write(res.text)


with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Phase', 'M^0_R', 'P_R', 'Q_R')) #Prints correctly                                                                                                            
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you add `textfile.close()` after the line `textfile.write(res.text)`? Trying to read from a file that is still open for writing could cause unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @myrtlecat Thank you so much, I knew it would be something silly. I did try .close() at the end of the file but that didn't seem to have an effect. Putting it where you suggested solved it. Thanks again!

Comment: Just be consistent - use the `with` context manager as you have elsewhere, then it will be closed for you when you leave that block.

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason you're looping over the file, breaking it up by commas, then using csv.writer to write out those rows as comma delimited? Seems you could just write it directly without the to & fro'ing.

Answer (score 0):

When you write data to textfile, you leave the file open. Therefore when you reopen it later, the cursor is already in the end of the file, and iterating over lines only continues forward from the cursor, not from the beginning of the file.

Fix this by closing file after opening:

```
textfile = open("textfile.txt","w")
textfile.write(res.text)
textfile.close()
```